# Custom List view with button click event

Tags: java, android, custom-lists

I would like to add click event into two button which are in Custom List View . My custom list view extends Base Adapter . I don't know how to write it . Help me Please .
Here's is my Adapter Code : I also read some other posts but they don't work for me .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter    {


private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public Resources  res;
ListModel getList = null;
int i=0;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList data,Resources resLocal) {

    activity = a;
    this.data = data;
    res = resLocal;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {

    if(data.size() <= 0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView txt_Name;
    public TextView txt_Status;
    public ImageButton imgbtn_senka;
    public ImageButton imgbtn_fuenka;
    public TableRow tblrow_status;
    //public TableRow tblrow_btn;
    public RelativeLayout layoutbtn;
    public ImageView image;


}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        //Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_Name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberName);
        holder.txt_Status = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberStatus);
        holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayer);
        holder.imgbtn_fuenka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnfusenka);
        holder.imgbtn_senka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnsenka);
        holder.tblrow_status = (TableRow)vi.findViewById(R.id.tblrowstatus);
        holder.layoutbtn = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.layoutbutton);


        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size() <= 0){

        holder.txt_Name.setText("No Data");

    }
    else{

        getList = null;
        getList = (ListModel) data.get(position);
        if(getList.getMemberStatus() == 3){


            holder.tblrow_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.layoutbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(getList.getEntry() == 0){
                    Log.i("abc", getList.getEntry()+"");
                 //holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/senka.png",null,null));
                holder.imgbtn_senka.setImageResource(R.drawable.fusanka);
                holder.imgbtn_senka.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        else{


            holder.tblrow_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.layoutbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(getList.getEntry() == 0){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("未確認");
            }
            else if(getList.getEntry() == 1){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("参加");
            }

            else if(getList.getEntry() == 2){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("不参加");
            }
            else if(getList.getEntry() == 3){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("取消");
            }
        }


         holder.txt_Name.setText(getList.getMemberName());
         String url="http://10.0.2.2/football365/Photo/"+getList.getImage();

         try {
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("http://10.0.2.2/football365/Photo/"+getList.getImage(),null,null));



    }




    return vi;
}



}
```

Comment: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."_ So please provide more information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use follow code:

```
      if(convertView==null){

    //Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.txt_Name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberName);
    holder.txt_Status = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberStatus);
    holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayer);
    holder.imgbtn_fuenka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnfusenka);
    holder.imgbtn_senka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnsenka);
    holder.tblrow_status = (TableRow)vi.findViewById(R.id.tblrowstatus);
    holder.layoutbtn = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.layoutbutton);
    // add this line
    holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.imgbtn_senka.setOnClickListener(this);
    // do for how many object that you want


    vi.setTag(holder);
}
```

and in onClick method:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId())
     {
       case R.id.btnfusenka:

        break;
       case R.id.btnsenka:

         break;
     }
```

you must import follow line,

```
  import View.OnClickListener
```

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (CustomAdapter) . That's the error shown

Comment: did you implements OnClickListener in CustomAdapter class?

Comment: you must import follow line, `import View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Add it before `return` of your `CustomAdapter's` `getView()`,

```
holder.imgbtn_senka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do your imgbtn_senka buttons stuff  

            }
        });
```

Comment: I already tried this one . Not working .  Thanks for concern .

Comment: really, can you post that code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside `getview`

```
 holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // write your code here

        }
    });
```

Use this attribute in list view.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is follow:

1.In the getView() function write the view.onClickListener
(suppose its a button) so write

```
holder.BUTTON_NAME.setON(new View.onClickListener)

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do your imgbtn_senka buttons stuff  

            }
        });
```